# Can Solr be used as an alternative to cache?

Tags: postgresql, caching, solr, ehcache

We are using Postgresql for persistence, ehcache as our cache. We have recently introduced Solr for enabling faster searches (for fuzzy and exact searches).

So my question is : Can Solr be tuned in such a way that it can replace ehcache? (say by running in cloud-mode or so)

Just to add some context to the question:

We have a bunch of tables to store contact information. Ehcache is currently being used to get these contacts for a given ID. Solr will be used extensively for search related operations. Since Solr is already doing the search... why not replace Ehcache (as in some way it is like : searching with a given ID) provided the performance is not compromised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In additions to other reasons why **No** would be an answer, is also the granularity of changes. Lucene (underlying library) stores data in a read-only form. Solr adds updatable documents on top of that, but making them visible is still a heavy operation. Recent versions of Solr made it easier and faster with soft-commits, but the price of making a change visible is still non-trivial.

So, it is really not optimized for updating/caching a single value. The data structures are optimized for a multiple document update and then fast search with caching over that temporarily read-only state.

Comment: I don't disagree with your conclusion, because I dislike using Solr as a document store, (vs a search index) but if the use case is "latest verison of a document by id", that's what Realtime Get is for: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/RealTime+Get

Comment: Sure, Real Time Get improves access speed but at the loss of search functions and it is still not optimized for it. So, possible, but not recommended for switching from something specifically designed for such operations.

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a shot, but it's unlikely anyone will have a definitive answer to such a vague question. https://lucidworks.com/blog/2012/07/23/sizing-hardware-in-the-abstract-why-we-dont-have-a-definitive-answer/ is four years old now but still relevant. The answers will depend entirely on what you need to do.

So, some generic statements:

- SolrCloud or not is unlikely to be an issue that effects your decision. Use it if you want Solr to handle replication and index managment. Don't, if you'd rather do it yourself.
- Solr is fast, (given enough memory) so it's certainly *possible* you could get rid of a caching layer. Only you know your requirements though.
- Read through https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCaching, particularly you might be interested in the QueryResultCache.

Comment: Firstly thanks for the nice explanation. I have edited the question to provide some context. Please let me know your views.

Comment: Ok, so Solr is particularly useful for two things, fuzzy search characteristics, and relevance-based ordering. ID lookup in Solr IS quite fast, but as pointed out in other answers, it's going to be hard to beat an in-memory cache, even if your whole solr index is cached in memory anyway. It's a pretty common pattern to use Solr only to get the list of matching, ordered ids, and use that to get the actual document contents from a persistent store like postgres. If you already have a cache in front of postgres for speed purposes, I don't see much reason to change that.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is: **No**

**Reason**:

`cache` is in memory, but the index of solr is on disk (except the part been cached).

Reading memory is over thousands of times quicker than reading disk.

So, solr can't be used as a **general** purpose cache, in that case `ehcache` or `memcached` or `redis` would be a better choice.

What solr good at is its search ability, `analyzer & tokenizer & filter`, but not cache.